# how to make background content scrollable with CSS when Masked on the foreground

Tags: html, css

I want to be able to scroll through the bg content, even when I have the overlay opened.
How can I also make the background content scrollable?
I've also checked other places where there are similar questions raised, but hasn't helped me for this particular instance.

CSS:

```
.main{
  position: relative;
}
.masked-content {
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
 
}
.mask {
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: default;
    height: 150px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 1000;
    }
```

JS:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="masked-content">This is some text covered by the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the mask</div>

  <div>
    <div class="mask">Some contents above the mask</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/43w7xzL0/

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `pointer-events: none` on the mask to let the scroll events through to the element(s) behind.

```css
.mask {
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  ...
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

**Update regarding clicks:** If the mask content really is simple text like your example you could simplify this by using a CSS pseudo element for the mask. This would solve both the scroll and click issues and streamline your markup.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.masked-content {
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
  transform: translate(0,0,0);
}

.masked-content::after {
  content: 'This is the mask';
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  height: 150px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
  <div class="masked-content">This is some <a href="https://google.com">text covered by</a> the mask This is some text covered by the mask This is some <a href="https://google.com">text covered by</a> the mask This is some text covered by the mask This is some <a href="https://google.com">text covered by</a> the mask This is some text covered by the mask This is some <a href="https://google.com">text covered by</a> the mask This is some text covered by the mask This is some <a href="https://google.com">text covered by</a> the mask This is some text covered by the mask This is some <a href="https://google.com">text covered by</a> the mask This is some text covered by the mask This is some <a href="https://google.com">text covered by</a> the mask This is some text covered by the mask This is some <a href="https://google.com">text covered by</a> the mask This is some text covered by the mask This is some <a href="https://google.com">text covered by</a> the mask This is some text covered by the mask This is some <a href="https://google.com">text covered by</a> the mask This is some text covered by the mask This is some <a href="https://google.com">text covered by</a> the mask This is some text covered by the mask This is some <a href="https://google.com">text covered by</a> the mask This is some text covered by the mask This is some <a href="https://google.com">text covered by</a> the mask This is some text covered by the mask </div>
```

**Click blocking with javascript:** If the idea above is unworkable you could add an event listener to swallow clicks with a bit of javascript instead:

```js
document.querySelector('.masked-content')
  .addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
```

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
}

.masked-content {
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.mask {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: default;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 1000;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="masked-content">This is some text covered by the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above
    the maskSome contents above the <a href="http://google.com">maskSome contents above the maskSome</a> contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above
    the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above
    the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above
    the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the mask</div>

  <div>
    <div class="mask">Some contents above the mask</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, how could I miss that :(

Comment: hi @ray hatfield: sorry I just realized one issue: how can I disable click event when pointer-events: none. It allows me to scroll but also clicks- I want to disable clicking-https://jsfiddle.net/k8xpchtv/

Answer (score 1):

I think that is more easy if you do it using js.
Just add This script to your code.

```html
<script>
  const mask = document.querySelector('.mask');
  const maskContent = document.querySelector('.masked-content');
  mask.addEventListener('mouseover', (e)=> {
    e.target.style.display='none';
  });
  maskContent.addEventListener('mouseleave', (e)=> {
    mask.style.display='flex';
  });
</script>
```